# Pandas count specific values in groupby results

Tags: python, pandas

I just learned how to group a Pandas DataFrame with datetime index by dates. How can I count the number of specific values ('Passed' or 'Failed') on each day that is returned by the groupby?

My goal is to calculate daily yield: yield = passed_count/(passed_count + failed_count).

```
import pandas as pd
import random

data = [random.choice(['Passed','Failed']) for i in range(100)]
times = pd.date_range('20180101',freq='3H',periods=100)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':data},index=times)
group = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1D'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) or [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html), reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and last divide by `sum`:

```
np.random.seed(142)

data = np.random.choice(['Passed','Failed'], size=100)
times = pd.date_range('20180101',freq='3H',periods=100)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':data},index=times)
#print (df)
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1D'), 'A']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
#alternative 
#df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1D'))['A'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
df1['new'] = df1['Passed'].div(df1.sum(axis=1))
#alternative
#df1['new'] = df1['Passed'].div(df1['Passed'].add(df1['Failed']))

print (df1)
A           Failed  Passed    new
2018-01-01       5       3  0.375
2018-01-02       5       3  0.375
2018-01-03       4       4  0.500
2018-01-04       4       4  0.500
2018-01-05       4       4  0.500
2018-01-06       3       5  0.625
2018-01-07       4       4  0.500
2018-01-08       5       3  0.375
2018-01-09       4       4  0.500
2018-01-10       4       4  0.500
2018-01-11       4       4  0.500
2018-01-12       7       1  0.125
2018-01-13       0       4  1.000
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I extract a row from the df1 result? df1['2018-01-13'] throws a KeyError.

Comment: @stephenb - You need `loc` like `print (df1.loc['2018-01-13'])`